# java regex replaceAll with negated groups

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to use the `String.replaceAll()` method with regex to only keep letter characters and `['-_]`. I'm trying to do this by replacing every character that is neither a letter nor one of the characters above by an empty string.

So far I have tried something like this (in different variations) which correctly keeps letters but replaces the special characters I want to keep:

```
current = current.replaceAll("(?=\\P{L})(?=[^\\'-_])", "");
```

Comment: Note that between square brackets, `'-_` means “_any character between `'` and `_`_”, which is probably not what you want. You should either escape the `-` or place it last before the `]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need lookahead, just use negated regex:

```
current = current.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}'_-]+", "");
```

`[^\\p{L}'_-]` will match anything that is not a letter (unicode) or single quote or underscore or hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Make it simplier :

```
current  = current.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z'_-]", "");
```

Explanation :
Match any char not in `a` to `z`, `A` to `Z`, `'`, `_`, `-` and `replaceAll()` method will replace any matched char with nothing.

Tested input : `"a_zE'R-z4r@m"`
Output : `a_zE'R-zrm`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is too complicated. Just specify the characters you want to keep, and use `^` to negate, so `[^a-z'_-]` means "anything but these".

```
public class Replacer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("with 1234 &*()) -/.,>>?chars".replaceAll("[^\\w'_-]", ""));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
String str = "Se@rbi323a`and_Eur$ope@-t42he-[A%merica]";
str = str.replaceAll("[\\d+\\p{Punct}&&[^-'_\\[\\]]]+", "");
System.out.println("str = " + str);
```

And it is the result:

```
str = Serbia'and_Europe-the-[America]
```